# Possible to create yammer custom API's?

Tags: yammer

Creating a custom analytics dashboard for yammer and looking at all the ways I can get data. While browsing the web I came across this

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/176/t/352016

> 'You can create an API to do this type of accomplish this type of functionality. You may join a 3rd party site https://stackoverflow.com/tour.'

Just wondering if anyone has done anything with creating an API?

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the response. You can't create additional APIs. All supported APIs are documented on the [Developer Site](https://developer.yammer.com/).